# Android: AsyncTask post different variable types

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I have class where am using `HttpURLConnection`,which am using to post String variables to my server:

```
public class SendPostRequestLocation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {}
```

Now if I need to send other type variables, for examples `Int`, or `Doubles`
.Do I need to create another almost same class, or  I need everything convert to `String` and use my only one class?Or if its possible to make my class more universal to work with different variables types?

Comment: You can just use Object. But that means lots of ugly checks and casting. I can't think of a good reason to do it, maybe you have a broader architectural decision to make

Answer (score 2):

Since everything in `HTTP` ends up being a `String`, the easiest way would be to convert the variable to a `String` and use the same `AsyncTask`.